# express-subdomain not redirecting subdomain.localhost get request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, subdomain

I am using an express.js package called [express-subdomain](https://github.com/bmullan91/express-subdomain) to facilitate requests to defined subdomains I set up.

As far as I understand, the subdomain constructor function expects an express router object which I pass to it from an exported router module.

What I have tried is as follows:

MAIN APP.JS SERVER FILE

```
var common = {
    express: require('express'),
    subdomain: require('express-subdomain')

};

common.app = common.express();

module.exports = common;

common.app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log(('app listening on http://localhost:3000'));
});

var router = require('./router/index');


// Error Handling
common.app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
});
```

router/index

```
 module.exports = function (){
        var common = require('../app');
        var router = common.express.Router();

        common.app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.send('Homepage');
        });


        common.app.use('/signup', require('./routes/signup'));
        common.app.use(common.subdomain('login', require('./routes/login')));
    }();
```

routes/login

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('login working');
});


router.get('/info', function (req, res) {

});
module.exports = router;
```

I have tried to access the login subdomain at the following urls:

```
http://login.localhost
http://login.localhost:3000
http://login.localhost.com
http://login.localhost.com:3000
```

Any clarification or assistance appreciated.

Comment: What is currently happening when you make a request to login.localhost? Also, when you say "defined," do you mean that you have explicity written the domains in your /etc/hosts file?

Answer (score 2):

author of express-subdomain here

A couple of things:

1. Hosts must be setup correctly - I'd recommend something like so in your /etc/hosts file.

`127.0.0.1       myapp.local
127.0.0.1       login.myapp.local`

For more information on this see https://github.com/bmullan91/express-subdomain#developing-locally

2. Register the subdomain routes before any others, including the homepage route. The order is very important
3. The pattern you're using in `/routes/index.js` is not advised (requiring a self invoking function). Exporting the Router like you done in `/routes/login.js` is cleaner.

Finally, If you're still stuck take a look at the source for express subdomain and in particular its tests.

Happy coding.

Comment: Any way you could look at this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53824495/express-subdomain-simple-setup-not-working